# Unable to access second disk after reinstallation of ubuntu

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04.1LTS on my laptop but I can no longer access my SSD drive that was installed on place of my CD-ROM. This was fully accessible before I reinstalled Ubuntu.
It is actually a 1TB disk

When I run sudo parted -l

I get

Error: /dev/sub: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA CT500MX500SSD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 509GB
partition Table: unknown

If I run
sudo file -s /dev/sda{,1,2}

I get
/dev/sdb:  data
/dev/sdb1: cannot open `/dev/sdb1' (No such file or directory) /dev/sdb2: cannot open` /dev/sdb2' (No such file or directory)

I’m not a Ubuntu expert so can someone please tell me how to fix it so I can access it, and get the full 1TB

I used to access this using
cd /cdrom

It contained lots of important data, but cd /cdrom now shows no files.

cd /cdrom
df .
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3      479077064 11421384 443246388   3% /

I don't think this is my second disk though

#######
Problem solved. I reformatted the second disk and now it all works fine.

Thanks for all your help

Thank you
Mark

Comment: Does this disk have any information? How it was "accessible"?

Comment: Yes, it has many GB of data - I used to just go to cdrom but when I go to cdrom now, it's empty

Comment: How are you mounting the disk to /cdrom?  You do this in the /etc/fstab file, using UUID instead of device (in case that changes). I don't think there is any automatic mount for /cdrom, but something might show up under /media/<username>/<uuid>.  Please add the terminal output from the df command (skip the loop devices).

Comment: What disks show up when you type `lsblk`

Comment: Problem solved. I reformatted the second disk and now it all works fine.

Thanks for all your help